# calculate the number of times a value needs to shift to complete 1 full cycle

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How can I calculate the number of times I will need to shift increment a "square" loop so that 1 full repeated cycle is completed?

**Image of a of 5 by 6 array requires an increment of 1-91 for 1 full cycle**
[image: 1 full cycle 1-91]

**Example: of a 5 by 6 array**

First "square" loop (which follows the green dot 18 shift increments are needed to complete 1 "square" loop cycle)
**1    2    3    4    5    6   12   18   24   30   29   28   27   26   25   19   13    7**

Second "square" loop (which follows the yellow dot 10 shift increments are needed to complete 1 "square" loop cycle)
**8    9   10   11   17   23   22   21   20   14**

Third "square" loop (which follows the orange dot 2 shift increments are needed to complete 1 "square" loop cycle)
**15   16**

**Static image and start of loop**

[image: Start of loop]

Example:

For the 1st outer square Loop (which follows the green dot it takes 90 increments or 5 "square" loop cycles to complete 1 full cycle

For the 2nd square Loop (which follows the yellow dot it takes 90 increments or 9 "square" loop cycles to complete 1 full cycle

For the 3rd square Loop (which follows the orange dot it takes 90 increments or 45 "square" loop cycles to complete 1 full cycle

**How can I calculate the number of times I will need to shift increment a "square" loop so that 1 full repeated cycle is completed?
The reason I ask is because I want to calculate these values for other m x n arrays**

**Animated image of square loops 1-91 this completes 1 full cycle**

[image: Animated full loop]

Comment: For an $m\times n$-array the length of the $k$-th loop is $4+2m+2n-8k$, where $k=1$ crresponds to the outer loop. Do you want the least common multiple of these lengths?

Comment: @Servaes yes LCM would work.  But how would I go about calculating that `90` increments are needed to make 1 full circle?  At the moment I animated it and counted it visually.  I would also like to calculate this `90` value but for × -arrays.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For an $m\times n$ array, the length of the $k$-th loop is
$$4+2m+2n-8k=2(2+m+n-4k),$$
where $k=1$ corresponds to the outer loop. The total number of shifts needed is then the least common multiple of these lengths, where $k$ runs from $1$ to $\ell:=\min\{\lceil\tfrac m2\rceil,\lceil\tfrac n2\rceil\}$. That is, your number is
$$2\cdot\operatorname{lcm}\left\{2+m+n-4k: 1\leq k\leq\ell\right\}.$$
As for how to compute this number effectively; I do not know if there is a simple expression, but for small $m$ and $n$ (let's say $m,n<1000$) a computer can compute this quite quickly. For example, here is a piece of Python code that will do the trick:

```
def gcd(a,b):
  if b == 0:
    return a
  else:
    return gcd(b,a%b)

def lcm(a,b):
  return a*b//gcd(a,b)

def NumberOfShifts(m,n):
  N = 1
  l = min(-(-m//2),-(-n//2))
  for k in range(1,l):
    N = lcm(N,2+m+n-4*k)
  return 2*N

m=5
n=6
print(NumberOfShifts(m,n))
```

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?